# Extending a UIViewController with a different NIB file

Tags: iphone, uitableview, inheritance, uiviewcontroller

Ok, I am definitely doing something wrong here...

I have create a BaseViewController that is the datasource and delegate of an matching NIB file containing a UITableView. This controller is responsible pretty much for getting data from a remote web service, creating the cells, and populating the UITableView.

So now I want to create a SearchViewController, so that I can get a UISearchBar that a user can enter a search query, post it on the web service, get the results and populate a UITableView.

However most of the code (in retrieving the data/populating the UITableView) exists in BaseViewController. So the first thing I thought of is to create the SearchViewController as an extension of BaseViewController with a different NIB file.

I've created the new NIB file called SearchView containing a UISearchBar and a UITableView and linked those two with the File Owners IBOutlets. (The UITableView IBOutlet is being inherited from BaseViewController)

So finally in my MainWindow.xib I've added a TabBarController and from the IB I've linked the UINavigationController to load the SearchViewController with View being loaded from SearchView. When I switch to the search tab, I am getting a SIG_ABORT with error:

`-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "SearchView" nib but didn't get a UITableView`

Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to proceed? I am sure most of you doing stuff with UITableView have reused code by extended a class. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Based on the error, I'm assuming that BaseViewController is derived from UITableViewController (which has a "tableView" field in it.) Based on your description I'm guessing that BaseViewController also has a "tableView" field in it. Are these assumptions and guesses correct?

In the SearchViewController nib, what is connected to the UIViewControllers "view" outlet?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I follow your description exactly, but what I think you should do is create your SearchViewController as a subclass of BaseViewController, like

```
@interface EventListViewController : UIViewController { ... }
```

Is that what you mean by "extending" BaseViewController?

And then you're using `[[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchView" bundle:nil]` to create your SearchViewController? I usually handle the initial view loading of my apps programmatically in the app delegate.

The error you get sounds like your IBOutlet connections are wrong somehow. Too bad you can't post a nib file here as easily as you can post code.

Comment: Yes sorry, this is exactly what I am doing. I am subclassing the BaseViewController. (Sorry I come from a different programming background :)) Well the problem might be that I am not calling initWithNibName because the SearchViewController is being loaded from an NIB with a TabBarController. In my MainWindow.xib I've added a TabBarController with 4 TabBar Items. The Search Tab Bar is a Navigation Controller and I've set the UINavigationController to load the NIB "SearchView"...

Comment: I always do my initial ViewController stuff programmatically in the app delegate. Trying to do it in Interface Builder confused me years ago and I haven't had any reason since to try again. Although, now that I've done it in code so many times, the IB connections will probably make more sense to me. So, I suggest loading the Tab Bar Controller etc. manually in the app delegate if you're still having trouble.